# R to Python: separate a column (in dataframe) into several columns in dataframes

Tags: python, r, pandas

I'm having a small issue. I need to split a column (data) into multiple columns.

Original column

```
0     3.0
1     3.0
2     3.0
3     3.0
4     3.0
5     2.0
6     3.0
7     3.0
...   ...
15    3.0
dtype: float64
```

I need to get an output as follows:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    2    3    3
[3,]    3    3    3    3
[4,]    3    3    3    3
```

Using R, I used: `max_u <- matrix(max_u, nrow = 4)`

But I'm trying to find an equivalent way to do it in Python.

Comment: In pandas the underlying structure is numpy, so try numpy's `reshape` method.  you may need something like `mycolumn.values.reshape(4,4)`

Answer (score 0):

Solution is:

```
max_u = max_u.reshape(-1,4)
```